# MSBuild - Publish multiple build configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution that contains a website project, I've got a PublishProfile (.pubxml) setup for the Release build and this is configured within TFS build using /p:PublishProfile=BuildServerPublish. The profile looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>R:\MyApp\Live</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

TFS is configured to do a CI build of the Release branch whenever a check-in occurs, and this works great.

The issue I now have is that we want to add in some staging servers to the process (QA, UAT, etc), and whilst I have created Build Configurations and Config Transforms for these in Visual Studio, the publish profile can only define a single build configuration (in this case Release), and moreover the build definition in TFS can only specify a single publish profile.

The end goal is to have TFS build the site and publish it multiple times (once for each build config) in separate subfolders, whilst doing the appropriate config transform for each. For example:

R:\MyApp\Qa
 - containing the "QA" tranformed version of the config

R:\MyApp\Uat
 - containing the "UAT" tranformed version of the config

R:\MyApp\Live
 - containing the "Release" tranformed version of the config

My first idea was to create separate publish profiles for each build configuration, and then reference these in the build profile, using something like: 
/p:PublishProfile=BuildServerQaPublish|BuildServerUatPublish|BuildServerLivePublish

..but TFS was having none of that.
My next idea was to have multiple publish settings within a single profile, like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Qa</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>R:\MyApp\Qa</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Uat</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>R:\MyApp\Uat</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>R:\MyApp\Live</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

..but that didn't work either.
The only other thing I can think of doing is to have multiple build definitions set up, each on referencing a separate publish profile, but I'm trying to avoid this for two reasons; firstly because it'll mean having lots of build definitions (there's more than just this solution, across multiple project teams), and secondly because it'll effectively mean building the same code repeatedly, just to do different config transforms.

It would be good if this could be done without editing the csproj files, although if that's the only solution then so be it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have exactly this issue, did you ever find a CLI solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a release tool to manage your releases.

TFS has a release tool named as Release Management, it can continuously deploys your app to a specific environment for each separate stage: development, test, staging, and production. Refer to this link for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593700(v=vs.120).aspx